# Chainging proxychains DNS port

Tags: kali-linux, dns, proxychains, port

I am using a proxychains on Kali with a DNSCrypt nameserver which operates on port 443. When I start proxychains it tries to connect to the DNS server on port 53 and it returns a timeout. How can I change proxychains to use port 443 for the proxy_dns instead of port 53? And why the DNSCrypt server operates on port 443 and not on port 53?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to this site! Can you share your `proxychains.conf`? Take care to anonymize/delete any sensible information!

Comment: Thank you! I haven't touched the `proxychains.conf` file, only the proxyresolv file. I am using [DNSCrypt.uk](https://www.dnscrypt.uk/) as an example in the file. [proxychains.conf](https://paste2.org/7OPJU77Y) [proxyresolv](https://paste2.org/VHV3VbVC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know why `DNSCrypt` uses the port `443`, maybe to prevent conflict with existing DNS resolvers on the same system.

That said, this line in your `proxyresolv`

```
dig $1 @$DNS_SERVER +tcp | awk '/A.+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/{print $5;}'
```

assumes a *standard* port `53` for the resolver.

Just add the option `-p 443` to `dig`:

```
dig $1 @$DNS_SERVER -p 443 +tcp | awk '/A.+[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/{print $5;}'
```

to make it use `DNSCrypt` port (assuming `DNS_SERVER=139.59.200.116` is your `DNSCrypt` server.

Comment: DNSCrypt uses 443 because it is DNS over TLS. I also use it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro well, TLS can be used on _any_ port by _any_ protocol. Probably they chose `443` because is "well known" for security (as to the general public).

Comment: yes, that too, because  it is usually open in most firewalls. see dnscrypt.info